# Regular expression for Cisco enable prompt

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am looking for a generic regular expression that can match with any of these enable prompts,

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:ios#
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:R1#
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:CX1-SF#
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:~#
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:cisco#
```

and should not match with config prompts like these,

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:ios(config)#
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:R1(config)#
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:R1(config-if)#
```

I started with something like this,

```
(.*?)RP/\d+/RP[01]/CPU\d+:.+#\s*?
```

But it is also matching with config prompts,

https://regexr.com/6km9a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind before the `#` that prohibits `)`.

```
(.*?)RP/\d+/RP[01]/CPU\d+:.+(?<!\))#\s*?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could omit matching parenthesis or a newline right after the colon using `[^()\n]*` and then matching until till the #

Note that you can omit the `\s*?` as it is the last part of the pattern and non greedy, so it will not match any characters.

```
(.*?)\bRP/\d+/RP[01]/CPU\d+:[^()\n]*#
```

**Explanation**

- `(.*?)` Capture group 1, match as least as possible chars
- `\bRP` Match RP preceded by a word boundary
- `/\d+/RP[01]/CPU\d+:` The specific pattern till the `:`
- `[^()\n]*` Optionally match any char except the listed using  [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `#` Match literally

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/2UxvIA/1).

---

Or you could exclude matching "config" between parenthesis:

```
(.*?)\bRP/\d+/RP[01]/CPU\d+:(?!\w+\(config\b[^()\n]*\)).+#
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q0yOha/1).